# Benchmarking with Hyperledger Caliper for Hyperledger fabric which are in different machine

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-caliper

Caliper (v.0.4.2) is installed and setup the configuration on my machine (laptop), and ready to communicate with the existing deployed fabric network which is in google-cloud. To communicate these two caliper and fabric network, I have provided connection profile of org1(where my contract is deployed). I found the error and not solved.
How to solve this error?

> Error: Could not find details for contract ID

---

**Below is information for finding the solutions of given problem.**

---

**Caliper is startup using following commands**

```
gopal@gopal:~/workspace/newcalliper/caliper-workspace$ npx caliper launch manager --caliper-workspace ./ --caliper-networkconfig networks/networkConfig.yaml --caliper-benchconfig benchmarks/myAssetBenchmark.yaml --caliper-flow-only-test --caliper-fabric-gateway-enabled
```

---

**Setting on networkConfig:**

```
name: Fabric Calier test network
version: "2.0.0"
 
caliper:
 blockchain: fabric
 sutOptions:
   mutualTls: false
channels:
 - channelName: mychannel
   contract:
   - id: abc
 
organizations:
 - mspid: Org1MSP
   identities:
     certificates:
     - name: 'adminorg1'
       admin: true
       clientPrivateKey:
         path: '../fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp/keystore/key.pem'
 
       clientSignedCert:
         path: '../fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/cert.pem'
   connectionProfile:
     path: '../fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/connection-org1.yaml'
     discover: false
```

---

**benchmark config :**

```
test:
    name: basic-contract-benchmark
    description: test benchmark
    workers:
      type: local
      number: 1
    rounds:
      - label: readAsset
        description: Read asset benchmark
        txDuration: 5
        rateControl: 
          type: fixed-load
          opts:
            transactionLoad: 1
        workload:
          module: workload/readAsset.js
          arguments:
            contractId: abc
```

---

**readAsset.js and submit transaction :**

```
'use strict';
 
const { WorkloadModuleBase } = require('@hyperledger/caliper-core');
 
class MyWorkload extends WorkloadModuleBase {
   constructor() {
       super();
   }
   // this initializeWorkloadModule is called by the workloadeModuleBase.js from the caliper inside.
   //and send to sutAdptor as a request to simulate.
   async initializeWorkloadModule(workerIndex, totalWorkers, roundIndex, roundArguments, sutAdapter, sutContext) {
       await super.initializeWorkloadModule(workerIndex, totalWorkers, roundIndex, roundArguments, sutAdapter, sutContext);
           const request = {
               contractId: this.roundArguments.contractId,
               contractFunction: 'GetAllAssetCategory',
               invokerIdentity: 'adminorg1',
               contractArguments: [],
               readOnly: false
           };
           await this.sutAdapter.sendRequests(request);
   }
 
   async submitTransaction() {
       const myArgs = {
           contractId:this.roundArguments.contractId,
           contractFunction: 'GetAllAssetCategory',
           invokerIdentity: 'adminorg1',
           contractArguments: [],
           readOnly: false,
           targetPeers:['peer0.org1.exmple.com'],
           targetOrganizations:['peer0.org1.example.com'],
           orderer:['orderer0.org1.example.com'],
           channel:['mychannel']
       };
      
       await this.sutAdapter.sendRequests(myArgs);
   }
   async cleanupWorkloadModule() {
       for (let i=0; i<this.roundArguments.assets; i++) {
           const assetID = `${this.workerIndex}_${i}`;
           console.log(`Worker ${this.workerIndex}: Deleting asset ${assetID}`);
           const request = {
               contractId: this.roundArguments.contractId,
               contractFunction: 'GetAllAssetCategory',
               invokerIdentity: 'adminorg1',
               contractArguments: [],
               readOnly: false
           };
 
           await this.sutAdapter.sendRequests(request);
       }
   }
}
 
function createWorkloadModule() {
   return new MyWorkload();
}
 
module.exports.createWorkloadModule = createWorkloadModule;
```

---

**Caliper Log:**

```
2021.01.26-23:11:54.759[32m info [39m [caliper] [caliper-worker]    Info: worker 0 prepare test phase for round 0 is starting...
2021.01.26-23:11:54.764[90m debug[39m [caliper] [workload-module-base]  Workload module initialized with: workerIndex=0, totalWorkers=1, roundIndex=0, roundArguments={"contractId":"abc"}
**2021.01.26-23:11:54.771[32m info [39m [caliper] [caliper-worker]  Worker [0] encountered an error during prepare test phase for round 0: Error: Could not find details for contract ID abc
    at V2FabricGateway._sendSingleRequest (/home/gopal/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-fabric/lib/connector-versions/v2/FabricGateway.js:156:23)**
    at V2FabricGateway.sendRequests (/home/gopal/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-core/lib/common/core/connector-base.js:78:39)
    at MyWorkload.initializeWorkloadModule (/home/gopal/workspace/newcalliper/caliper-workspace/workload/readAsset.js:20:35)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
2021.01.26-23:11:54.772[32m info [39m [caliper] [caliper-worker]    Info: worker 0 prepare test phase for round 0 is completed
2021.01.26-23:11:54.773[90m debug[39m [caliper] [process-messenger]     Process "10624" sent message: {"sender":"10624","recipients":["10611"],"type":"prepared","content":{},"date":"2021-01-26T17:26:54.773Z","error":"Error: Could not find details for contract ID abc"}
2021.01.26-23:11:54.774[31m error[39m [caliper] [worker-message-handler]    Error while handling "prepare" message for Worker (10624): Error: Could not find details for contract ID abc
    at V2FabricGateway._sendSingleRequest (/home/gopal/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-fabric/lib/connector-versions/v2/FabricGateway.js:156:23)
    at V2FabricGateway.sendRequests (/home/gopal/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-core/lib/common/core/connector-base.js:78:39)
    at MyWorkload.initializeWorkloadModule (/home/gopal/workspace/newcalliper/caliper-workspace/workload/readAsset.js:20:35)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
2021.01.26-23:11:54.793[90m debug[39m [caliper] [process-messenger]     Process "10624" handling message: {"sender":"10611","recipients":["all"],"type":"exit","content":{},"date":"2021-01-26T17:26:54.793Z"}
2021.01.26-23:11:54.798[90m debug[39m [caliper] [worker-message-handler]    Handling "exit" message for Worker (10624): {"sender":"10611","recipients":["all"],"type":"exit","content":{},"date":"2021-01-26T17:26:54.793Z"}
2021.01.26-23:11:54.799[32m info [39m [caliper] [worker-message-handler]    Worker#0 is exiting
2021.01.26-23:11:54.799[90m debug[39m [caliper] [worker-message-handler]    Handled "exit" message for Worker (10624)
```

---

Additionally, when `discover: true` for the Connection profile, only peer show the info on console as

```
2021-01-27 14:25:22.811 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 098 unary call completed grpc.service=discovery.Discovery grpc.method=Discover grpc.peer_address=202.52.76.41:33878 grpc.peer_subject="CN=fabric-common" grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=1.059889ms
```

but none of orderer and CA shows any info of caliper request which was submitted as transaction using gateway .  Following error is additionally shown in caliper console  :

```
2021.01.27-19:25:35.887 info [caliper] [connectors/v2/FabricGateway] Successfully connected user with identity adminorg1 to a Network Gateway
2021.01.27-19:25:35.892 info [caliper] [connectors/v2/FabricGateway] Generating contract map for user adminorg1
2021-01-27T13:40:39.803Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Committer- name: orderer0.org1.example.com:7050, url:grpcs://localhost:7050, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
2021-01-27T13:40:39.808Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - Failed to connect to remote gRPC server orderer0.org1.example.com:7050 url:grpcs://localhost:7050 timeout:3000
2021-01-27T13:40:39.810Z - error: [DiscoveryService]: _buildOrderer[mychannel] - Unable to connect to the discovered orderer orderer0.org1.example.com:7050 due to Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Committer- name: orderer0.org1.example.com:7050, url:grpcs://localhost:7050, connected:false, connectAttempted:true

2021-01-27T13:40:42.844Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Endorser- name: peer0.org1.example.com:7051, url:grpcs://localhost:7051, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
2021-01-27T13:40:42.844Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - Failed to connect to remote gRPC server peer0.org1.example.com:7051 url:grpcs://localhost:7051 timeout:3000
2021-01-27T13:40:42.845Z - error: [DiscoveryService]: _buildPeer[mychannel] - Unable to connect to the discovered peer peer0.org1.example.com:7051 due to Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Endorser- name: peer0.org1.example.com:7051, url:grpcs://localhost:7051, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
2021.01.27-19:25:42.854 info [caliper] [caliper-worker] Info: worker 0 prepare test phase for round 0 is starting...
2021.01.27-19:25:42.861 info [caliper] [caliper-worker] Worker [0] encountered an error during prepare test phase for round 0: Error: Could not find details for contract ID abc
```

---

Edit : Added additional results of setup with `discover`  true and false case to define the problem clearly.

---

Thank you!

Comment: related question is asked in given link, but not solved and not fully explained. here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65296447/difficulty-creating-a-benchmark-test-using-hyperledger-caliper

Comment: In  case of discover : true, I expect my remote machine IP instead of localhost in given info caliper console. here is detail : 2021-01-27T13:40:42.845Z - error: [DiscoveryService]: _buildPeer[mychannel] - Unable to connect to the discovered peer peer0.org1.example.com:7051 due to Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Endorser- name: peer0.org1.example.com:7051, url:grpcs://localhost:7051, connected:false, connectAttempted:true

Comment: In case of discover : true, I found that, if contract ID is not set properly then it throws the error with the IP that is provided in the Connection Profile. see the  result  : 2021-01-27T14:55:41.676Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - Failed to connect to remote gRPC server orderer0.org1.example.com url:grpcs://35.224.172.187:7050 timeout:3000 .

Comment: with discover set to true, to stop the underlying node-sdk from converting urls to localhost, you need to also specify `--caliper-fabric-gateway-localhost=false` on your command line.

Comment: In my test, --caliper-fabric-gateway-localhost=false did not affect my benchmark in discover : false, and still gave me the same result of complete test with report. And this complete test possible in remote machine with discover: true and  false both.  On using --caliper-fabric-gateway-localhost=false,  discover: false do not gave any error but discover:true gave error as : error: [DiscoveryService].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your network config file is not complete. Caliper still has to explicitly know about the chaincodes (aka contracts) that have been deployed onto your channels.
Referring to this section in the tutorial
https://hyperledger.github.io/caliper/v0.4.2/fabric-tutorial/tutorials-fabric-existing/#populating-the-template-file
you will see a section on `Channels` which describe adding information about channels to the network config file. For example from that tutorial it defines this section

```
channels:
  - channelName: mychannel
    contracts:
    - id: basic
```

This states that there is a channel `mychannel` that has a contract (chaincode) deployed with an id of `basic`

Comment: I have added contract ID after fetching from the network. and it still show the same error. Is there other attributes to adds on configuration of caliper ?

Comment: Could you update this stackoverflow with your new network config file to see if there are any obvious problems with it now.

Comment: I have checked with discover true and false case and I have  updated the question with additional results to make problem clear.

Comment: You've made a mistake in your network config file. You used the word `contract` not `contracts` ie you are missing the `s`

Comment: After adding contract ID  in contracts field, above problem of  ' Error: Could not find details for contract ID'  is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample and complete configurations for caliper in one machine and hyperledger fabric is in another machine.

---

**Starting caliper :**

```
npx caliper launch manager --caliper-workspace ./ --caliper-networkconfig networks/networkConfig.yaml --caliper-benchconfig benchmarks/myAssetBenchmark.yaml --caliper-flow-only-test --caliper-fabric-gateway-enabled --caliper-fabric-gateway-localhost=false
```

---

**network Configuration:**

```
name: Fabric Calier test network
version: "2.0.0"
 
caliper:
 blockchain: fabric
 sutOptions:
   mutualTls: false
channels:
 - channelName: mychannel
   contract:
   - id: abc
 
organizations:
 - mspid: Org1MSP
   identities:
     certificates:
     - name: 'adminorg1'
       admin: true
       clientPrivateKey:
         path: '../fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp/keystore/key.pem'
 
       clientSignedCert:
         path: '../fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/cert.pem'
   connectionProfile:
     path: '../fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/connection-org1.yaml'
     discover: false
```

---

**Benchmark configuration**

```
test:
    name: basic-contract-benchmark
    description: test benchmark
    workers:
      type: local
      number: 1
    rounds:
      - label: readAsset
        description: Read asset benchmark
        txDuration: 5
        rateControl: 
          type: fixed-load
          opts:
            transactionLoad: 1
        workload:
          module: workload/readAsset.js
          arguments:
            contractId: abc
```

---

readAsset.js and submit transaction :

```
'use strict';
 
const { WorkloadModuleBase } = require('@hyperledger/caliper-core');
 
class MyWorkload extends WorkloadModuleBase {
   constructor() {
       super();
   }
   // this initializeWorkloadModule is called by the workloadeModuleBase.js from the caliper inside.
   //and send to sutAdptor as a request to simulate.
   async initializeWorkloadModule(workerIndex, totalWorkers, roundIndex, roundArguments, sutAdapter, sutContext) {
       await super.initializeWorkloadModule(workerIndex, totalWorkers, roundIndex, roundArguments, sutAdapter, sutContext);
           const request = {
               contractId: this.roundArguments.contractId,
               contractFunction: 'GetAllAssetCategory',
               invokerIdentity: 'adminorg1',
               contractArguments: [],
               readOnly: false
           };
           await this.sutAdapter.sendRequests(request);
   }
 
   async submitTransaction() {
       const myArgs = {
           contractId:this.roundArguments.contractId,
           contractFunction: 'GetAllAssetCategory',
           invokerIdentity: 'adminorg1',
           contractArguments: [],
           readOnly: false,
           targetPeers:['peer0.org1.exmple.com'],
           targetOrganizations:['peer0.org1.example.com'],
           orderer:['orderer0.org1.example.com'],
           channel:['mychannel']
       };
      
       await this.sutAdapter.sendRequests(myArgs);
   }
   async cleanupWorkloadModule() {
       for (let i=0; i<this.roundArguments.assets; i++) {
           const assetID = `${this.workerIndex}_${i}`;
           console.log(`Worker ${this.workerIndex}: Deleting asset ${assetID}`);
           const request = {
               contractId: this.roundArguments.contractId,
               contractFunction: 'GetAllAssetCategory',
               invokerIdentity: 'adminorg1',
               contractArguments: [],
               readOnly: false
           };
 
           await this.sutAdapter.sendRequests(request);
       }
   }
}
 
function createWorkloadModule() {
   return new MyWorkload();
}
 
module.exports.createWorkloadModule = createWorkloadModule;
```